# Floated div not same height as parent

Tags: html, css, css-float, height

I want to make two divs next to each other inside a parent div

Like this:

```
<--------- 70% ----------> <-- 30% -->
|-------------------------|----------|
|                         |          |
|                         |          |
|-------------------------|----------|
```

It only works when the parent got a fixed height, but I want the parent to be auto in order the content to fit perfectly inside the parent.

When the parent doesn't got a fixed height:

```
|-------------------------|----------|
|                         | content  |
|        content          |----------|
|                         |
|-------------------------|
```

CSS:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  height: auto;
}

.biginside {
  background-color: pink;
  height:100%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.smallinside {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="biginside">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="smallinside">
    <p>content<p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Checkout the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/LQQTm/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `table-cell` and `table` displays.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/LQQTm/5/)

```
.pink {
    width: 70%;
    display: table-cell;
}
.blue {
    display: table;
    width: 100%
}
.red {
    width: 30%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same, so I did it like that:

`<div class="pink">
    <div class="red"><p>red's content</div></div>
    <p>pink's content</p>
</div>`

You can do it only when you are sure that the red div is larger then the pink one. 
the another way (if the heights can be different) is with jQuery:

`if($('.pink').height() < $('.red').height()){
    $('.pink').height($('.red').height());
} else {
    $('.red').height($('.pink').height());
}`

Good luck!